# How to assign %%parameter to variable?

Tags: batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

How to assign %%parameter to variable?

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%A IN (connections.txt) DO (
   set USER=%%A

   echo A=%%A
   echo USER=%USER%
)
```

Output of this code:

```
A=user1
USER=
```

How to assign parameter %%A to variable USER?

Comment: This might be of some use http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter %%A was correctly assigned to USER variable, but USER value is not correctly shown.

To use the current value of a variable that was modified *inside* a FOR loop, you must use Delayed Variable Expansion, that is, change the percent by exclamation mark this way:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%A IN (connections.txt) DO (
   set USER=%%A

   echo A=%%A
   echo USER=!USER!
)
```

and include this line at beginning:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Otherwise, the value of %USER% is the one the variable had *before* entering the FOR loop.